# UV are always stretch, checker test always shown rectangle

Tags: uv

Regarding the the title. I having trouble  understanding the Blender 's UV unwrapping.[image]

As the image shown the checker are all rectangle instead of a square. Through toggling "stretch" function the UV are shown to be fine, but the checker are all rectangle.

[image]

Apart from that(referring to 2nd image). I found it weird that blender's "Unwrap" the short pillar(A) as the way it shown on the 2nd image. Shouldn't it be like the UV of pillar B?.

I have try addon like, Textool, Texel Denstity and Magic UV. However, all the result are all the same.

Blender file

[image]

Comment: maybe first try to apply the scale and unwrap again?

Comment: yup, it works thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tab into **Edit mode** and press `A` and press `U` and choose the unwrap option. Then select all your UVs by pressing `A` and pressing `S` to scale it. After I did that everything looked fine, there was no stretching. Your object has no issues it is perfect and has good geometry with perfectly marked seams. And also as moonboots said apply your scale by selecting your object in **Object mode** and pressing `Ctrl`+`A` and selecting the scale option.

[image]